# Perl - handle files with non english (Japanese) names

Tags: perl, file

I'm trying to find whether a file exists (using the -e option) and to read from it (using `@lines = <FILE>`), both are not working with names (of files or directories) that contain (for instance) Japanese chars.

I'm using ActivePerl 5.14.1 and win7. This is a short sample of what I'm doing:

```
if(-e 'C:\\test\\本のテれキス\\本のテれキス.txt') {
    print "exist";
} else {
    print "ne";
}
```

Although the file exists I get `ne`

Comment: You should search whether a topic has come up before. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5D+unicode+filenames → http://p3rl.org/Win32::Unicode::Native http://p3rl.org/PerlIO::fse http://p3rl.org/Path::Class::Unicode

Comment: You are doing something strange you don't tell us since it should work. `perl -e "if ( -e '日本語' ) { print 'OK'; }"` works if 日本語 exists.

Comment: [Try using a single forward slash instead of escaped backslashes](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29311).

Comment: You said `Windows`. Are you using Windows code pages, UTF-16, or UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you give it a try with a file in your current directory, just in case the '\' doesn't work as expected.